# PHP/AJAX: Data at HTML table is not display well after selected a data at dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Now I alreday create a PHP page that contain dropdown list and a table. When I select a 'factory' from the dropdown list, all the the meeting rooms that belong to the factory will display in a table below.

Below is my current code.

room.php

```
              <p>Select Factory:</p>

              <select onChange="getroom(this.value);"  name="factory" id="factory" class="form-control" >
                      <option value="">Select</option>
                      <?php $sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM factory");
                      while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {  
                      ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $row['Fac_ID'];?>"><?php echo $row['Fac_Name'];?></option>
                      <?php
                      }
                      ?>
                      </select>
            </div><br>
            <div class="table">
            <table class ='table table-striped table-bordered' align='center'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th width='30%'>ID</th>
                      <th width='30%'>Room</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td name="room" id="room-list"></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
                </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
```

get_room.php

```
            <?php
            require_once "../../config/configPDO.php";
            require_once "../../config/check.php";

            if(!empty($_POST["factory_id"])) 
            {
            $sql =$conn->query("SELECT * FROM room WHERE Fac_ID = '" . $_POST["factory_id"] . "'");
            ?>
            <?php
            while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row["Room_ID"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["Room_Desc"]; ?></option>
            <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
```

Let say if I Select a factory value= 'F05'

it will display the table like this,

https://scontent.fkul14-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/69574235_10216833731128752_2692416896514392064_n.jpg?_nc_cat=109&_nc_oc=AQlQCoOsH3NAf3PmoFj-PWJVw21qvliKsgVGS_AC2IdDiXG05QDDV2ZJNUwTasrdNwU&_nc_ht=scontent.fkul14-1.fna&oh=0766c26b7f129b2d1b7be862830724b6&oe=5E0FAB49

How I want to make sure all the display is separate by td?

Comment: Currently, how do you show your data in here `<td name="room" id="room-list"></td>
                    </tr>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know how you wrote the code of javascript, but the code of get_room.php generate a options value, and you need a td field. in this case change options for td and tr ex..

```
'<tr><td>'.$row["Room_ID"].'</td><td>'.$row["Room_Desc"].'</td></tr>';
```